# WebStorm Emmet outputting tags as HTML entities

Tags: ide, webstorm, emmet

I am using Emmet in WebStorm.

The output of this line:

```
ul#nav>li.item$*4>a{Item $}
```

Must be:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="item1"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instead, this is what I am getting:

```
&lt;ul id="nav"&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
    <!-- /#nav -->&lt;li class="item1"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!-- /.item1 -->&lt;a href=""&gt;Item 1&lt;/a&gt;&lt;li class="item2"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!-- /.item2 -->&lt;a href=""&gt;Item 2&lt;/a&gt;&lt;li class="item3"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!-- /.item3 -->&lt;a href=""&gt;Item 3&lt;/a&gt;&lt;li class="item4"&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
    <!-- /.item4 -->&lt;a href=""&gt;Item 4&lt;/a&gt;
```

It works fine in Sublime Text and Atom. Can anyone please help?

*Update (added screenshots)*

[image: WebStorm screenshot 1]

[image: WebStorm screenshot 2]

Comment: Where are you doing it? What file type is that? What context? Some screenshots would be great to see. It's kind of working here (at very least no encoding for `<` and `"` like you are having

Comment: It's an AngularJS project in a component HTML. I've added the screenshots.

Comment: It works fine here in plain HTML file.. If you try at the very beginning of the file -- will it be the same? Will it work if you disable ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins? No other obvious ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to uncheck `Escape` in `Preferences | Editor | Emmet | HTML`, `Filters enabled by default`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.